# Password Change causing Authentication Problem

Tags: login, password, authentication

I use Ubuntu 14.04. I had set up a log in password earlier which i removed a few days ago. Even the "user accounts" tab shows no password. Any new software/application download asks me for a password authentication, but it doesn't accept either my old password or no password. Even changing the password from the use accounts tab is not working, i click on the unlock icon at the top of the use accounts interface and it prompts for a password but it neither accepts my old password nor it accepts no password. this is very frustrating, any ideas please ?

Answer (score 0):

By removing that password, you removed yourself from the group of users that can perform administrative stuff.

In order to re-enable it, access as `root` from GRUB ([Recovery mode](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode)), then remount the disk with write privilege

```
mount -o remount,rw /
```

then setup your new password

```
sudo passwd USERNAME
```

NB: **USERNAME** is your user's name, usually all with lowercase, no spaces and so on...